# lmer model with random intercept and random slope doesn't lead to adequate regression

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I'm trying to fit a random intercept random slope model to my data. In this data, I have different patients, all with three implanted electrodes (LAN/SAN/PAN), and I'm looking at the effect of StimRate on the response 'result'.
Using lmer I'm fitting this model, but the individual coefficients per subject/electrode combination do not seem to be correct.

Data:

```
df<-structure(list(subject = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", 
"5", "6", "8", "9"), class = "factor"), Electrode = c("LAN", 
"LAN", "LAN", "SAN", "SAN", "SAN", "PAN", "PAN", "PAN", "LAN", 
"LAN", "LAN", "SAN", "SAN", "SAN", "PAN", "PAN", "PAN", "LAN", 
"LAN", "LAN", "SAN", "SAN", "SAN", "PAN", "PAN", "PAN", "LAN", 
"LAN", "LAN", "SAN", "SAN", "SAN", "PAN", "PAN", "PAN", "LAN", 
"LAN", "LAN", "SAN", "SAN", "SAN", "PAN", "PAN", "PAN", "LAN", 
"LAN", "LAN", "SAN", "SAN", "SAN", "PAN", "PAN", "PAN", "LAN", 
"LAN", "LAN", "SAN", "SAN", "SAN", "PAN", "PAN", "PAN"), StimRate = c(170, 
255, 350, 170, 255, 350, 170, 255, 350, 170, 255, 350, 170, 255, 
350, 170, 255, 350, 170, 255, 350, 170, 255, 350, 170, 255, 350, 
170, 255, 350, 170, 255, 350, 170, 255, 350, 170, 255, 350, 170, 
255, 350, 170, 255, 350, 170, 255, 350, 170, 255, 350, 170, 255, 
350, 170, 255, 350, 170, 255, 350, 170, 255, 350), result = c(6.52102722288664, 
9.22019774432065, 26.5655048141819, 14.5, 20, 24.25, 1.9142135623731, 
2.92080962648189, 4.30277563773199, 63.9763476887368, 88.9562197097544, 
140.606864480896, 60.4829340051411, 64.0882999323977, 89.6212532523402, 
9, 15.0118980208143, 25.8648808045487, 66.4275, 67.2522222222222, 
111.332727272727, 90.972, 117.55, 141.881666666667, 20.255, 30.91125, 
57.06, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.513333333182, 1.46499999986639, 
1.60045618855114, 2.32320260275458, 2.50266082562552, 2.21762809295402, 
1.92141610251248, 1.62939845265917, 2.45633949992756, 32.8, 48.51, 
66.19625, 26.655, 36.3875, 39.335, 9.2425, 14.5775, 26.85125, 
73.92, 58.73, 86.8066666666667, 94.4475, 100.1125, 81.7683333333333, 
15.3075, 44.595, 47.395)), row.names = c(7L, 8L, 9L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 
61L, 62L, 63L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 97L, 
98L, 99L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 
133L, 134L, 135L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 160L, 161L, 
162L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 187L, 188L, 189L), class = "data.frame")
```

Model:

```
RISM =  lmer(result ~  StimRate + (1 + StimRate | subject/Electrode), data = df)
summary(RISM)
cf<-coef(RISM)
```

When plotting the regression (intercept/slope), is does not fit well, for example for LAN/subject

2: When applying a linear regression on only this data it fits well however. What is going wrong with the random intercept random slope model?

```
df_subset<- df[which(df$subject==2 & df$Electrode=="LAN"),]
lm(results~StimRate, data = df_subset)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you say that the model does not fit well. When I plot the predicted values they look very reasonable.

Comment: `df$predicted <- predict(RISM); ggplot(df, aes(StimRate, result, group = subject)) + geom_point() + geom_line() + geom_line(aes(y = predicted), color = 'firebrick') + facet_grid(Electrode ~ .)`

Comment: scaling `StimRate` by 100 eliminates a convergence warning and improves the overall model fit, although fixed-efficient coefficients/SEs/t values don't change noticeably (beyond the obvious effects of scaling).  Random effects are slightly different, but not radically so. Please give more detail on what you see that looks wrong!

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. When I fit the model, then for example for subject 2/electrode=LAN, the intercept is 10.77 and slope 0.2436, which is not a nice fit for that line; while the intercept is -12.73 and slope 0.428 when using lm only for subject2/electrodeLAN seperately, which is a very nice fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** the differences are smaller than you think; a stimulation rate of 0 is far from the body of your data, so small differences in the slope can extrapolate to (apparently) large differences in the intercept. (I don't know whether the intercept is scientifically meaningful in your case, but if so I would worry about extrapolating from 170 to 0 ...) The mixed model is doing exactly what it's designed to do, which is to shrink extreme values of slope and intercept toward the population mean. Nevertheless, there are some wrinkles to think about.

### improving the model fit

When I run your model I get a warning:

> Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.884042 (tol = 0.002, component 1)

As it turns out this doesn't make much difference to the fixed-effect estimates, but it does affect the subject/electrode level predictions slightly. I solved this problem by scaling the stimulation rate by 100 (scaling and centering predictors often helps with convergence problems).

At the same time, I'm going to fit the individual linear models (for later comparison).

```r
## original model
RISM <-lmer(result ~  StimRate + (1 + StimRate | subject/Electrode), data = df)
## rescale StimRate and re-fit
df2 <- transform(df, StimRate = StimRate/100)
RISM2 <- update(RISM, data = df2)
## fit individual linear models
RISM3 <- lmList(result ~ 1 + StimRate | interaction(df$subject,df$Electrode), df)
```

### `coef()` doesn't do what you think it does

Unfortunately, `coef()` returns the coefficients adjusted for a *particular level of the random effect*; in this case, it returns coefficients *either* at the subject level, or for the adjustments at the subject/electrode level (but **not including the subject-level random effect**).  Let's look at the coefficients for subject 2/electrode LAN:

```r
## subject-level adjustment *only*
coef(RISM)[["subject"]]["2",]  ## 10.4666 0.1925383
## subject:electrode-level only
coef(RISM)[["Electrode:subject"]]["LAN:2",]  ##  10.77296 0.2435873
## separate linear model
coef(RISM3)["2.LAN",]  ##  -12.72759 0.4280286
```

Here's a correct way to get the estimated intercept and slope for 2/LAN from the mixed model, accounting for both levels (unfortunately slightly unwieldy):

```r
p_int <- predict(RISM,
                 newdata=data.frame(Electrode = "LAN",
                                    subject = "2",
                                    StimRate = 0))
p_slope <- predict(RISM,
                   newdata=data.frame(Electrode = "LAN",
                                      subject = "2",
                                      StimRate = 1)) - p_int
 c(p_int, p_slope)
         1          1 
11.2101702  0.3340758
```

This is different from either of `coef()` outputs, but as you can see it doesn't address your basic question ("why are the mixed-model and `lm()` results so different?")

### separate fit vs mixed model

To answer this I want to show you a picture.

```r
## predictions for both mixed models (unscaled and scaled), and lm()
pframe <- with(df, data.frame(subject, Electrode, StimRate,
                              p_lmer = predict(RISM),
                              p_lmer2 = predict(RISM2),
                              p_lmList = predict(RISM3)))
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())

gg0 <- ggplot(df, aes(StimRate, result)) + geom_point() +
    facet_grid(subject ~ Electrode, scale = "free")

(gg0
    + geom_line(data = pframe, aes(y=p_lmer), colour = "red") 
    + geom_line(data = pframe, aes(y=p_lmer2), colour = "blue")
    + geom_line(data = pframe, aes(y=p_lmList), colour = "purple")
    + expand_limits(x=0)
    + theme(panel.spacing=unit(0,"lines"))
)
```

The separate and mixed-model fits are different — otherwise there would be no point doing the mixed model anyway. Focusing on the 2:LAN panel in the plot below, the fits are not very different. The separate fit (purple) **is** a slightly better fit to the data for these three particular points; the mixed model fits (blue and red, blue is masking the red here) have a slightly decreased slope to fit in better with the overall population of subject/electrode combinations. Projecting back to a stimulation rate of zero, that produces the difference between the intercept of -12 (separate) and +11 (mixed). In general there's not much difference between the blue/red (scaled and unscaled mixed model fits) predictions, except for subjects 5 and 6. The y-axis scales on these panels are much smaller, so the differences are more apparent. (Subject 5 appears to be completely unresponsive: perhaps this was an experimental problem?  Subject 6 responds much less than the remaining subjects; the mixed model interprets most of this variation as noise and adjusts the predicted slope toward the population mean.)

[image]

Replotting with fixed scales (take out `scale = "free"` in the `facet_grid()`) gives a slightly different view. Now the fits look much more similar; the only really different mixed vs. separate slopes are in 2:LAN and 9:SAN, which are the most extreme slopes in the population (and hence are shrunk most toward the population mean).

[image]

It *might* make sense to define the intercept as the value at the lowest stimulation rate (170), which you can do either by subtracting 170 from the predictor variable or by predicting the response at a stimulus rate of 170.

Comment: What a great great answer Ben, many many thanks! That helps a lot!

Comment: Since this worked out so well ;), does anyone also knows whether it makes sense to plot the overall regression of the model with the confidence interval. And if so, how can you create the confidence interval of the regression?